# Is there a way the be alerted of changes to a shared iCal calendar?

Tags: ical, sharing, notifications

I've created a calendar in iCal that I share with colleagues, who I have given permission to edit. Everything works fine except that I see no way to receive alerts or notifications when they make changes to events in the calendar. They all report that they were given the option to see alerts when they subscribed, but I (as creator of the calendar) was not given any (that I saw).

Is there a way to configure a shared calendar so that the *creator* of the calendar can be notified when other users make changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When viewing your calendars at iCloud.com, click the "shared calendar info" button next to the calendar of interest (Button is white for unshared calendars, green for shared). In the new window, check the "email me when this calendar is changed" box.

Now, whenever someone else updates the calendar you will get an email with the change.

Comment: Weird that it doesn't do this directly in iCal.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea of subscribing to your calendar seems odd or has other side-effects, you could always set up a second account to receive / process / forward the change notices.

It seems odd we have to resort to these workarounds since the machinery is there to be self notified or bcc when updates get sent from the server directly. It won't allow you to add yourself from the iCloud calendar web app and checking the send me an email when changes happen checkbox seems ineffective in generating mails presently.